# In each part, determine whether the three vectors lie in a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I could not find the part that told me how to find out this question at all. I do know that three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are linearly independent if and only if they do not lie in the same plane when they have their initial points at the origin. But how am I supposed to find out if they lie in the same plane to begin with?

EDIT: Never mind I found the answer. Sorry for all the fuss.

Comment: You should try to understand what you have written: the vectors are in a plane if and only if they are linearly dependent.

Comment: ohhh woops my bad ok just gotta solve the system of eqs then

Comment: If you have found the answer, please share it with people. It can be used by other students in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

These vectors are coplanar if and only if
$$(v_1\wedge v_2)\wedge v_3=0$$

Answer (score 1):

three vectors in R3 are linearly independent if and only if they do not lie in the same plane when they have their initial points at the origin

so for part a) solving the system of linear equations leads to a solution that is linearly independent, therefor they do not lie in the same plane.

Answer (score 0):

**- My opinion:**

Vectors are on the same plane if they are linearly dependent. You can check for it by doing Av1 + Bv2 + Cv3 = 0; please note that A, B, and C should not equal to 0.

We can conclude that if few vectors are linearly **dependent**, then they are on the same plane. However, if they are not linearly **independent**, then they are not on the same plane.

Please let me know if this explanation can be improved.